# If I attach my USB webcam to USB to AV converter and then plug it in AV to HDMI mini adapter, will it work?

Tags: usb, hdmi, webcam

What I want is to connect my webcam directly to my hdmi monitor... So theoreticly if i buy a usb to AV converter cable and then attach this to a mini AV To HDMI adapter then connect it to my monitor will I will be able to get a picture?
[[image: usb to av]

[image: av to hdmi]

Comment: Does your monitor have software to run a webcam?  Most monitors would not have such software and what you are trying to do would not work on monitors without software.

Comment: No it does not.. but all I really need is to view, not recording or adjusting or anything like that. If u google UVC webcam to hdmi you will see a chinese company named Febon who did just that, but it is quite difficult to obtain  it because it is not sold in Europe .. I guess if you are sure my idea would not work then ill take your word and will not waste my time and effort..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I attach my USB webcam to USB to AV converter and then plug it in AV to HDMI mini adapter, will it work?

No.

A webcam needs to plug into a computer.  A computer with drivers for the webcam, and software to display the video out HDMI.  I've seen some pretty fancy TVs with USB ports that might be able to avoid the need for a computer in the middle but if you are looking for a USB adapter then I'm guessing the TV doesn't have a USB port, or you tried that already and it didn't work.

This is not likely to be a $20 fix.  More like $200.

Answer (score 5):

While I wouldnt call these USB to RCA adapters a scam, its close.  They are made for *very* specific devices - not webcams.  The seller/manufacturer probably has some left over from an order and is just dumping them on various shopping sites trying to sell off the remainder.  They often do not disclose the fact they do not do what the buyer thinks and hope they dont return them.

Based on the picture you show, there is no active electronics to convert the USB signal to a RCA composite/component signal.  This would be done on the host device - which your webcam with almost absolute certainly does not have.

Answer (score 4):

> Does your monitor have software to run a webcam?  ... No it does not.

You cannot do what you are trying to do. A webcam needs software to run it, so you need a computer between your webcam and your monitor, or a webcam with built in software to be a computer. I have not seen that.

That is, you need a traditional setup for a webcam.

Answer (score 2):

I've been searching for something like this for a different application.  The Febon device is the only thing I've found so far.  But I also discovered a different possible solution--it's a bit overkill but it's cheap enough that it might do what you want.

Get a PC on a stick device (around $150).  It is a fully functional Windows computer that plugs into an HDMI port and accepts USB inputs.  So you can plug in a mouse and keyboard to control it, connect the webcam and set it up to display full-screen, and your image is now displayed on your monitor of choice.  Of course, you can also do whatever else you want because it's a fully functional computer.

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi has a TV out signal (composite, S-VIDEO,CVBS). Connect the webcam to a Raspberry Pi Zero or any type of Raspberry Pi, then you can connect the output to a TV.